# How to import a complicated .txt file with matlab

Tags: database, matlab, import

I have issue importing my data into matlab: [my data](http://genomics-pubs.princeton.edu/oncology/Data/CarcinomaNormalDatasetCancerResearch.txt)
there is numbers and strings etc.

Comment: Add some more details

Comment: could you specify (give a brief example) of what you want your data matrix to look like in Matlab? for example {description, tumor1, tumor2 .... tumor34} . Alternatively, if you wish to load in each line as a separate set (so you don't have to worry about the format) that is also possible, but it would mean difficulties when trying to access your data

Comment: Yes i would like my data to look like {description, tumor1, tumor2 .... tumor34}

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could split the values from the text and save them in sperate Celltables/matrices. The way the data is now I don't see how it could easily be resolved.
Is the top part (with the personal) data relevant to the bottom part or could this be wirtten in another table? Then I would split this...